# unable to populate the array in alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

this is my full alpine.js code

```
    @{
    int MOOD = 167;
}
<div x-data="{ 'showModal': false, variants: [] }" x-init="fetchVariants()" x-bind:data-product-id="@MOOD">

    <!-- Trigger for Modal -->
    <button type="button" @@click="showModal = true">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto" x-show="showModal">
        <!-- Modal inner -->
        <div class="max-w-3xl px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg" @@click.away="showModal = false"
             x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90"
             x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
            <!-- Title / Close-->
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                <h5 class="mr-3 text-black max-w-none">Title</h5>

                <button type="button" class="z-50 cursor-pointer" @@click="showModal = false">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                         stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                              d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div x-data>
                <ul>
                    <template x-for="price in variants" :key="price">
                        <li>
                            <p>Price: <span x-html="price"></span></p>
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function fetchVariants() {
        const productId = document.querySelector('[x-bind\\:data-product-id]').getAttribute('data-product-id');
        const url = `/Home/ProductDesc?ProductId=${productId}`;

        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                variants = res.variant.map(item => ({ price: item.price }));
                // Update the variants property with the new array of prices
                Alpine.store('variants', variants);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    }



</script>
```

but trying different things i am not able to populate price. any idea what i am doing wrong here

I see this when entering console.log(Alpine.store('variants'))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `fetchVariants()` can correctly fetch the data from the backend, the problem is that you put the data in `Alpine.store('variants')` store object, but you are using the empty `variants` local property in the component. You should use the `$store` object in the template as well:

```
<template x-for="price in $store.variants" :key="price">
```

Note: if `price` is really a price value, then it is not a good candidate for `:key` because two items can have the same price. Use an unique id or something for the `:key`.

Comment: $store.variants not working

Comment: Do you see the correct values if you print `Alpine.store('variants')` in the fetch function?

Comment: see to it in my edit

Comment: JSON.stringify(Alpine.store('variants')) it displaying [{"price":444},{"price":44},{"price":55}] . i am getting somewhere how can i use JSON.stringify(Alpine.store('variants')) in above code

Comment: `$store.variants` should work in the templates. Could you fix the others errors in your code first and try again?

Comment: they are related to other files not related to this file

Answer (score 0):

```
 @{
    int MOOD = 167;
}
<div x-data="{ 'showModal': false, variants: [] }" x-init="fetchVariants()" x-bind:data-product-id="@MOOD">

    <!-- Trigger for Modal -->
    <button type="button" @click="showModal = true">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto" x-show="showModal">
        <!-- Modal inner -->
        <div class="max-w-3xl px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg" @click.away="showModal = false"
             x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90"
             x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
            <!-- Title / Close-->
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                <h5 class="mr-3 text-black max-w-none">Title</h5>

                <button type="button" class="z-50 cursor-pointer" @click="showModal = false">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                         stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                              d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div x-data>
                <ul>
                    <template x-for="variant in variants" :key="variant.price">
                        <li>
                            <p>Price: <span x-text="variant.price"></span></p>
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function fetchVariants() {
        const productId = document.querySelector('[x-bind\\:data-product-id]').getAttribute('data-product-id');
        const url = `/Home/ProductDesc?ProductId=${productId}`;

        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                const variants = res.variant.map(item => ({ price: item.price }));
                // Update the variants property with the new array of prices
                Alpine.store('variants', variants);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Changed @@click to @click for the button events.
Changed x-html to x-text for displaying the price value.
Updated the assignment of the variants array in the fetchVariants function to properly map the prices from the fetched data.
Stored the variants array in the Alpine.js store using Alpine.store for easier access within the Alpine component.
Make sure the server response from the /Home/ProductDesc endpoint returns the expected data structure with the variant property containing an array of objects with a price property.

Comment: it is not working. removing Alpine.Store can also work?